# Why does jqXHR.done() return jqXHR object?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqxhr

Received jqXHR object from my `$.post` query contains `done` function. But I realized that this function returns just its jqXHR object:

```
$.post(query, function(a,b,jqXHR) {
  jqXHR === jqXHR.done() //true
});
```

How shoud I interpret that?

Comment: The `jqXHR` object is a superset of the native XMLHttpRequest object. In jQuery it is a deferred object, that also has the jQuery methods that deferreded objects have. One of those methods is `done()`, and as `done ()` also *returns* the deferred object, you're comparing the exact same object, and comparing an object to itself, returns `true`

Comment: So, in that situation, why XMLHttpRequest returns itself with done()? Should I interpret it just as 'true' value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `jquery`'s ajax call return a Promise, any of `done()`, `fail()`, `always()`, and `then()` functions will return the `jqXHR` object in order for the Promise to work correctly.

More information can be found here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#callback-functions